# JavaFx Progress Indicator freezes when I run another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2

So I have been trying to implement a progress indicator with no luck. I am not sure I understand managing threads with JavaFx very well, despite having read a bit about the Platform.RunLater and Tasks. So here is my use case.

My program allows users to connect to a database and look at some of the schemas and other objects in the database. Sometimes connecting to a large database and pulling up all its tables and info takes a while, so I would like to show a progress indicator. I am not trying to update the progress at all I would just like to make the progress indicator visible at a value of -1 while the process is running to pull everything from the database. Ideally I will have a progress indicator loaded in from an FXML file invisible. When I start the process of pulling info from the database I would like to make it visible.

When trying to make my progress visible it never showed up, so I decide to start out having it visible and making it invisible, just to see what happens. The progress indicator rotated nicely when I opened the program up, but as soon as I try to connect to the database it stopped rotating and just froze. I assume this is what happens when I try to make it visible too which is why it was never showing up.

The following is my current code, I would appreciate any detailed help with explanations so I can understand what is going on. Thanks

from the method that is doing most of the work.

```
                //make progress indicator visible
                pi.setVisible(true);

                // separate non-FX thread
                ExtractorThread t = new ExtractorThread();
                t.setCp(cp);
                t.start();

                //Wait until the thread is done
                try{
                    t.join();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //Retrieve the dbextractor from the thread
                DbExtractor dbe = t.getDbe();
                //move on to the next page in the application
                this.caster.goToDataSource(c, cp, dbe);
```

The ExtractorThread which does the work.

```
private class ExtractorThread extends Thread{
    private ConnectionProperties cp;
    private DbExtractor dbe;

    public void run() {
        dbe = new DbExtractor(cp);
        try {
            dbe.extract();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }

    public DbExtractor getDbe() {
        return dbe;
    }

    public void setCp(ConnectionProperties cp) {
        this.cp = cp;
    }
}
```

If I am supposed to use the Platform.RunLater I am not sure where to use it or why. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the javafx.concurrent API. Extend Task instead of Thread:

```
private class ExtractorThread extends Task<DbExtractor>{
    private ConnectionProperties cp;

    public DbExtractor call() throws Exception {
        dbe = new DbExtractor(cp);
        dbe.extract();
        return dbe;   

    }


    public void setCp(ConnectionProperties cp) {
        this.cp = cp;
    }
}
```

Then do:

```
        //make progress indicator visible
        pi.setVisible(true);

        // separate non-FX thread
        final ExtractorThread t = new ExtractorThread();
        t.setCp(cp);
        t.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {
               DbExtractor dbExtractor = t.getValue();
               this.caster.goToDataSource(c, cp, dbe);
            }
        });
        t.setOnFailed(...); // similarly, to handle exceptions
        new Thread(t).start();
```

Comment: You my friend are my hero, this works just the way I need it to!

Answer (score 1):

I don't code JavaFX, and so I can't give you chapter and verse, but this line:

```
t.join();
```

will block the calling code until the background thread is through. Don't do this. Instead use some type of listener to get notified when the background thread finishes. If this were Swing, I'd use a PropertyChangeListener added to a SwingWorker to notify me when the background thread was done. I think that you can still use a PropertyChangeListener to do a similar thing with with JavaFX, but I cannot tell you if this would represent the canonical solution.

Also, don't extend Thread but instead implement Runnable. This won't fix your problem but is basic Java common sense.

Comment: Thanks, I have not really dealt with much multithreading in the past so this is helpful

Comment: @decal: If this were Swing, I'd use a PropertyChangeListener to notify me when the background thread was done. I think that you can still do this with JavaFX, but I cannot tell you a canonical solution.